# Transforming union to single select with the unions inside from clause

Tags: sql, xml, db2, union

Currently I have UNION's between 3 different `select` statements giving me three rows.  What I'm needing is to modify this to have the `union` inside the `from` clause so that I can generate more columns (if I understand the functionality).

Basically what is going on is that the existing framework is designed and built to have a single row of data returned to it and will require heavy modification to handle a multi-row result set (everything is getting parsed to xml before being passed to the front-end).

My biggest issue (I believe) is being able to differentiate between the three sub selects inside the primary.

Guarantees in the select

1) Each `select` inside the from will only produce a single row result set.

2) All result sets from inside of the `from` will have same column count and column names (inherent of `union` I believe)

For example...
I currently have

```
SELECT * FROM A
    UNION
SELECT * FROM B
    UNION
SELECT * FROM C
```

Doing it this way produces a three row result set.

What I'm wanting if possible is....

```
SELECT cost as CurrentSelectedCost, /* from first select */
       cost as PreviousCost, /* from second select */
       cost as NextCost /* from third select */
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM A
        UNION
    SELECT * FROM B
        UNION
    SELECT * FROM C
)
```

Now I'm guessing that I will need to alias the different select statements that are within the `from` clause, but I'm having issues getting that to function.  The examples that I've found on here didn't seem to address the need to have all `select` statements inside of `from` differentiated.  If this has been answered on here a link will suffice no reason to re-invent the wheel (I may just not know the terminology to search for)  Also the database is a DB2 instance running on an iSeries

Comment: Can you give more details on the columns on the tables and the relationships between them?  I get the feeling a join may well be appropriate but without understanding the data a bit better it is difficult to provide the best answer.

Comment: If the solution below doesn't solve the issue I'll try to provide a closer to reality example.  I'm just not allowed to copy and paste what I have and was trying to avoid having to rewrite it all (if possible).  If I have to do so I'd be happy to I was just hoping to avoid it.  Also whoever designed the tables didn't enforce any referential integrity it's all done with code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unify the columns retrieved from the three SELECT statements.

```
SELECT CurrentSelectedCost,
       PreviousCost, 
       NextCost 
FROM (
    SELECT cost as CurrentSelectedCost, 0 as PreviousCost, 0 as NextCost FROM A
        UNION
    SELECT 0 as CurrentSelectedCost, cost as PreviousCost, 0 as NextCost  FROM B
        UNION
    SELECT 0 as CurrentSelectedCost, 0 as PreviousCost, cost as NextCost  FROM C
) as COSTS
```

Comment: this will give 3 rows... not what the OP wanted.. ?

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this with a select* inside the from?

Comment: Can you please send the output table result that should be returned?

Comment: selected answer based on the closest solution.  I ended changing format to a join instead of union and a select*, but the overall format that you listed is what ended up working.  Since there was no 100% correct answer that straight solved my problem yours is what let me to a solution. ty much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SELECT COLNAME FROM A) CurrentSelectedCost, 
       (SELECT COLNAME FROM B) PreviousCost, 
       (SELECT COLNAME FROM C) NextCost 
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont think you need a union.  there does not appear to be any join condition so maybe this will do it:

```
SELECT A.cost as CurrentSelectedCost, /* from first select */
       B.cost as PreviousCost, /* from second select */
       C.cost as NextCost /* from third select */
FROM A,B,C
```

Comment: I've attempted this but the cross join (comma separated is cross join correct?) sends the query into several minutes where the union is generally sub 30seconds depending on other loads on server at any given time.